# XP is not booting after using ghost

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot, ghost

I have computer A with 2 working operating systems:

1. xp
2. windows 7

I used ghost to clone hard disk of A to hard disk of computer B, Then i tried the new hard disk:

1. Windows xp --> does not boot and keep restarting the computer.
2. Windows 7 --> Working perfectly.

Is there fast way to fix this ? since i will do it on hundreds of computers that already cloned in same way.

Comment: Clonezilla could work. I'm reading that some Ghost versions require C: and D: drives to be done separately. Clonezilla does a bit-for-bit clone, as long as you the destination drive is unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the hardware of Computer B may not be consistent with the hardware of Computer A. If that's the case, and if the hardware in Computer B is more modern that Computer A, it may not be compatible with Windows XP. Newer hardware is more likely to be compatible with Windows 7, as it's still a relatively recent OS.

I have my doubts that you'll get XP to run in a stable way on modern hardware (other than in a VM). However, you could try checking and enabling legacy settings within the BIOS of Computer B (e.g. Legacy Boot rather than UEFI if available).

Comment: i tried to use the cloned hard-disk on same computer ,same problem happened. it is known problem for ghost cloning.However i can not find solution for it,i have hundreds of computers which is cloned in same way and all have same problem.

Comment: OK, then it would seem to be a different issue. Will leave my answer here in case it's useful to others attempting clones to newer hardware.